# Ant: use include and exclude together

Tags: ant, include, fileset

OK, this seems like it should be really simple.  I'm using Apache Ant 1.8, and I have a target which does:

```
<delete file="output/program.tar.bz2"/>
<tar basedir="input" destfile="output/program.tar.bz2" compression="bzip2">
  <tarfileset dir="input">
    <include name="goodfolder1/**"/>
    <include name="goodfolder2/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/badfile"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.badext"/>
  </tarfileset>
</tar>
```

I want it to make a .tar.bz2 of input/goodfolder1 and input/goodfolder2, excluding files named "badfile", and excluding files with extension ".badext".  It's giving me a .tar.bz2, but it's including badfile and *.badext -- the excludes seem to be ignored.

The order of include/exclude doesn't seem to make a difference.  I tried wrapping the includes/excludes in a  (the docs say it's implicit?), but it made no difference.

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing, since [the manual has a very similar example](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html), though in a somewhat different context.

EDIT: It looks like it could be related to the `dir="input"` attribute: it's adding everything in "input", and then adding everything in the tarfileset to that.  Files I want appear twice in the program.tar.bz2, but files that are excluded only appear once.  But `dir` is mandatory, and I don't see how this is different from the examples in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the `<tarfileset>` itself is what was causing my problem.

If I remove that, and put the includes/excludes directly inside the `<tar>`, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use two `<tarfileset>` elements. The `<include>` and `<exclude>` elements are for files only. Not for directories. Example:

`<tar basedir="input" destfile="output/program.tar.bz2" compression="bzip2">
  <tarfileset dir="goodfolder1">
    <exclude name="**/badfile"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.badext"/>
  </tarfileset>
  <tarfileset dir="goodfolder2">
    <exclude name="**/badfile"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.badext"/>
  </tarfileset>
</tar>`

Comment: `include` and `exclude` patterns can be used for either files or folders. You may be thinking of `includesfile` and `excludesfile`.